# Объявление типа функции в Haskell

Tags: haskell

Пытаюсь перейти от Prolog к Haskell.

Надо сделать вычисление арифметического выражения.

Пишу рекурсивную программу, аналогичную программе на Prolog. Поскольку в списке Haskell, в отличие от Prolog, все элементы должны быть одного типа, использую тип [String]. Приходится преобразовывать аргументы к численному представлению, а результат вычисления – обратно в символьное.

Компилятор не пропускает.
Что-то не правильно с объявлением типов или это методическая ошибка?

```
cc :: (String b) => [String] -> b
cc (a:"*":b:t) = cc(c:t)
    where c=show(read a * read b)
cc (a:"/":b:t) = cc(c1:t)
    where c1=show(read a / read b)
cc (a:"-":t)   = show(read a - read(cc t))
cc (a:"+":t)   = show(read a + read (cc t))
cc (a:[])      = a
cc []          = 0
```

Ошибка следующая:

> ERROR file:.\e3.hs:18 - Undefined class "String"

Comment: ошибка говорит что типа String - нет

Comment: Для ознакомления с Haskell подойдёт [курс по функциональному программированию на Haskell от Дениса Москвина](https://stepic.org/course/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-Haskell-75).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Для начала обратите внимание на то, что у вас написано в объявлении типа функции.

Сообщение об ошибке, собственно и утверждает, что нет такого класса `String`. Действительно, `String` это не класс, это просто тип данных, список символов. Поэтому выражение `(String b) => ...` не имеет смысла.

Вероятно, `b` должно иметь числовой тип, для начала можно использовать конкретный, например, `Double`.

Таким образом, тип функции будет следующий: `[String] -> Double`.

Далее у вас есть проблемы с тем, что функция не всегда возвращает число, иногда она возвращает строку. Это уже так просто не исправить, нужно вносить некоторые изменения в логику работы программы.

Вам нужно пересмотреть способ разбора подобных выражений, и использовать более подходящие технологии программирования на Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

В объявлении вида

```
f :: (T a) => String => a
```

`T` - [класс типов](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) (typeclass), `String` - тип, `a` - любой тип, принадлежащий классу типов `T`.

`Int`, `Integer`, `Char`, `String` - всё это типы. Классы типов обозначают начичие у типа определённых "методов" (если выражаться в терминах ООП), то есть это что-то типа интерфейсов или абстрактных классов.

Например:

```
class T a where
    f :: a -> Int

    g :: a -> Int
    g x = (f x) ^ 2
```

Здесь мы объявляем класс типов `T` такой, что для любого типа `a`, принадлежащего `T`, существует функция `f` типа `f :: a -> Int`. Также к переменной этого типа `a` можно применить функцию `g`, которая уже реализована. Теперь мы можем сделать уже существующий тип (пусть это будет `String`) экземпляром (instance) класса `T`:

```
instance T String where
    f = length
```

Таким образом, для типа `String` функция `f` вернёт длину строки:

```
f "hello"    -- вернёт 5
g "hello"    -- вернёт (f x) ^ 2, или 25
```

Реализованная функция `g` тоже может быть переопределена в экземпляре класса:

```
instance T Int where
    f x = x
    g x = x + x
```

---

Теперь, возвращаясь к Вашему примеру. Сигнатура функции `cc` должна выглядеть так:

```
cc :: [String] -> String
```

это значит, что функция `cc` принимает список строк и возвращает строку. Но вообще использовать строки чтобы представлять различные типы значений - **очень** плохая идея (особенно в Haskell, с его потрясающей системой типов). Обычно вместо этого используют [алгебраические типы данных](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type) ([sealed classes](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#sealed-classes) в некоторых объектно-ориентированных языках). Не знаю, какие у Вас типы значений, но приведу пример со списком разных чисел (`Int` и `Float`), которые надо между собой сложить (напомню что оператор [`(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) в Haskell принимает два числа **одного** типа, принадлежащего к классу типов [`Num`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) - можно сложить или целое с целым, или дробное с дробным, но целое с дробным - нельзя):

```
data MyNumber = MyInt Int | MyFloat Float

mySum :: [MyNumber] -> MyNumber
mySum = foldl myAdd (MyInt 0)

myAdd :: MyNumber -> MyNumber -> MyNumber
myAdd (MyInt x) (MyInt y) = MyInt $ x + y
myAdd (MyInt x) (MyFloat y) = MyFloat $ (fromIntegral x) + y
myAdd f@(MyFloat x) i@(MyInt y) = myAdd i f
myAdd (MyFloat x) (MyFloat y) = MyFloat $ x + y
```